# Can we rename our ports in heat template ? Do they appear in VM in same order as listed in heat template?

Tags: openstack, openstack-heat

I want to create a VM with 3 SRIOV ports ( heat template pasted below).  I would like each port to appear with some specific name in VM, is it possible? . Is there a guarantee that port will appear in VM in order specified in heat template?

For Eg

```
resources:
  vm1_server_0:
    type: OS::Nova::Server
    properties:
      name: {get_param: [vm1_names, 0]}
      image: {get_param: vm1_image_name}
      flavor: {get_param: vm1_flavor_name}
      availability_zone: {get_param: availability_zone_0}
      networks:
        - port: {get_resource: vm1_0_direct_port_0}
        - port: {get_resource: vm1_0_direct_port_1}
        - port: {get_resource: vm1_0_direct_port_2}
```

1. Can I rename vm1_0_direct_port_0 to "eth0" and vm1_0_direct_port_1 to "10Geth0" and vm1_0_direct_port_2 to "10Geth1" in heat template itself ?
2. If above is not possible, I need to be sure of order with which they appear in lspci|grep "Virtual Function" ( if those are sriov ports) ie like vm1_0_direct_port_0 appearing as 0000:04.01.00 and next vm1_0_direct_port_1 as 0000:04:01.01 and vm1_0_direct_port_2 as 0000:04:01.02 ?  for me to rename using udev rules in VM.